# Setting react project session variables, sharing data between route components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router, react-typescript

I'm currently working on a react project where I'm sending data between routes. I've looked into context managers in React, but from what I can tell they are mainly used for wrapping components, and not getting and setting data.

Is there any simple way to initialize a project-global state Object = `{}` which can be written-to- and read-from easily throughout the project routes?

Here is a little example structure which emulates what I would like for this to look like:

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import App1 from "./App1";
import App2 from "./App2";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

const [globalNumber, setGlobalNumber] = // initialize some global counter at zero.

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/app1" element={<App1 />} />
        <Route path="/app2" element={<App2 />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`App1.tsx`:

```
const App1 = () => {
  const [globalNumber, setGlobalNumber] = // get state-setter and current value from global state
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setGlobalNumber(globalNumber + 1);
      }}
    >
      Click me to increment global number!
    </button>
  );
};
export default App1;
```

`App2.tsx`:

```
const App2 = () => {
  const [globalNumber, setGlobalNumber] = // get current global number
  return <h1>Global number is currently: {globalNumber}</h1>;
};
export default App2;
```

Here I'm using some imaginary `[globalNumber, setGlobalNumber]` state, and commented where there's code missing. The hope is then to be able to navigate to route `/app1`, click the button a few times, and have the number displayed on screen when navigating to route `/app2`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with using a React context. React Context providers are a way to pass "props" down to *distant* descendent component without explicitly drilling them down as props. These can be any value. It's common to provide some state and an updater function via a Context provider.

`react-router`'s `Outlet` component actually provides a context for just this use case of passing data to nested route components.

Example:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

export interface MyContext {
  globalNumber: number;
  setGlobalNumber: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
}
```

...

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Outlet // <-- import Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";
import App1 from "./App1";
import App2 from "./App2";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
);

const App = () => {
  const [globalNumber, setGlobalNumber] = React.useState<number>(0);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route // <-- layout route
          element={(
            <Outlet
              context={{ // <-- pass context value
                globalNumber,
                setGlobalNumber
              }}
            />
          )}
        >
          <Route path="/app1" element={<App1 />} />
          <Route path="/app2" element={<App2 />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Then in the nested route components use the `useOutletContext` hook to access the context value.

```
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MyContext } from '../types';

const App1 = () => {
  const { setGlobalNumber } = useOutletContext<MyContext>();

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setGlobalNumber(globalNumber => globalNumber + 1);
      }}
    >
      Click me to increment global number!
    </button>
  );
};
```

...

```
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MyContext } from '../types';

const App2 = () => {
  const { globalNumber } = useOutletContext<MyContext>();

  return <h1>Global number is currently: {globalNumber}</h1>;
};
```

[image: Edit setting-react-project-session-variables-sharing-data-between-route-components]

Comment: Great! This works very nicely. The only point I'd add is that for Typescript, you need to declare the type of the context when using `useOutletContext`. I.e. `setState<number>(0)` results in the following code to access one of the hook values: `const { globalNumber }: { globalNumber: number } = useOutletContext();`. Thanks!

Comment: @SteinnHauserMagnusson Oh, shoot, totally missed the typescript tag, sorry. Glad it's working for you though. I'll update my answer when I'm back at a computer, thanks for the heads up. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: Was my bad! Added the tags in retrospect